# Как применить antMatchers для resources в Spring Security?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

У меня есть контроллеры, которые используют стили CSS и шаблоны страниц, находящиеся в папке resources в проекте, абсолютный путь такой
*C:\Users\kakty\IdeaProjects\KafkaCon\src\main\resources***

**Проблема:**

Не удаётся настроить доступ через antMatchers для статических веб-ресурсов в папке resources

До прохождения аунтефикации стили не применяются, после того как пользователь залогинился, стили начинаются работать

Как я могу настроить работу Spring Security так, что бы стили и шаблоны начинали работать до авторизации пользователя ?

**Конфигурация:**

```
    @Bean
public SecurityFilterChain filterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf()
            .disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
            //Доступ только для не зарегистрированных пользователей
            //.antMatchers("/reg").not().fullyAuthenticated()
            //Доступ только для пользователей с ролью Администратор
            .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
            .antMatchers("/news").hasRole("USER")
            //Доступ разрешен всем пользователей
            .antMatchers("/", "/resources/**","/resources/static/**", "/resources/static/CSS", "/resources/templates" ).permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/reg").permitAll()
            //Все остальные страницы требуют аутентификации
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            //Настройка для входа в систему
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            //Перенарпавление на главную страницу после успешного входа
            .defaultSuccessUrl("/hello", true)
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .permitAll()
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login");
    return http.build();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У Spring Boot есть стандартный путь, по которому он берёт статические файлы. Это путь `/resources/static`, и в матчерах его указывать не надо, так как при получении ресурсов по URL этот путь отбрасывается.

В матчерах вы должны указывать те папки, которые лежат по пути `/resources/static`, без указания этой части.

Предположим, у вас есть следующие папки для ресурсов:

- `/resources/static/css` - для css-файлов
- `/resources/static/js` - для js-файлов
- `/resources/static/svg` - для svg-иконок

Тогда матчер для ресурсов должен выглядеть так:

```java
.antMatchers("/css/**", "/js/**", "/svg/**").permitAll()
```

Comment: Спасибо

Мне помогло это решение